# How to dynamically get the images from database into react carousel?

Tags: php, reactjs

I have an API in PHP for getting the images and want to display it in the following [react carousel](https://github.com/brainhubeu/react-carousel). I don't know where am I doing wrong but the images won't display on the carousel. I am trying this thing for the last three days but end up displaying nothing. Can somebody please help me.

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import "./cropSelection.css";
import Carousel, { Dots } from '@brainhubeu/react-carousel';
import '@brainhubeu/react-carousel/lib/style.css';
import 'react-image-picker/dist/index.css'
import axios from 'axios';

class CropSelection extends React.Component {
handleChange = selectedOption => {
  this.setState({ selectedOption });
  console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
};
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    selectedOption: null,
    image: "",
    slides: []
      //(<img src = "https://i.postimg.cc/wjfpKgHg/Apple-1.png" className="fruit-images" alt="Pomegranate fruit" />)
  }
  this.onPick = this.onPick.bind(this);
}
componentDidMount = () => {

  fetch('http://localhost/fruit_api/carousel_api.php')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    let slides = data.map((pic) => {
      return(
        <div key = {pic.img}>
          <img src = {pic.img} />
        </div>
      )
    })
    this.setState({
      slides: slides
    })
    console.log("state", this.state.slides);
  })
  .then(function(response){
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(function(response){
    console.error(response)
  });
}

onPick = (image) => {
  this.setState({image})
}    

render() {
     return (
         <div className="caurosel-div">

         <Carousel
          arrows
          slidesPerScroll={1}
          slidesPerPage={3}
          value={this.state.value}
          slides = {this.state.slides} 
          onChange={this.onchange}
          >
     </Carousel> 
    <Dots value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onchange} number={this.state.slides.length} />
    </div>
   );
  }
}
```

[image: output]

**carousel.php**

```
<?php
include_once('database/include.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "farmer_portal");

if(!$conn)
    die("Error connecting to DB". mysqli_connect_error());

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET")
{
    $sel = "SELECT link from images";

    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sel);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)
    {
        $users = array();
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            $details=array(
                "img" =>  $rows['link']
            );
            array_push($users, $details);
        }
        sendResponse(200,$users,'Images');
    }
    else 
    {
        sendResponse(404,[],'Images not available');
    }
}
?>
```

[image: developer tool's]

developer's tools image

Comment: Can you share your PHP code?

Comment: Yup, I've edited the question

Comment: What does the `sendResponse()` function do?

Comment: It echo's the data in json format...function sendResponse($resp_code,$data,$message){
    echo json_encode(array('code'=>$resp_code,'message'=>$message,'data'=>$data));

Comment: Can you see that response in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: Yes, It displays all my images links..

Comment: I've added the image of developer's tools

Comment: What is the html here, I suppose if you just use the map function on the state variable in the render function, And store all the array of images in the state, It should work.

Comment: This looks related to the package maybe, Can you try removing the div you are wrapping the image in.

Comment: Also this.state.value needs to be initialized at 0. And update everytime the image shifts

Comment: Removed but it's not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209778/discussion-between-somangshu-goswami-and-abhishek-marubadi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured the problem is in the assignment of the data. The `data` object consists of the whole response body and because of that the map function could not work. The better way to write this would be

```
fetch('http://localhost/fruit_api/carousel_api.php')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(data => {
       const { data } = data // getting data attribute out of the response object
       let slides = data.map((pic, k) => {
           return(
              <div key = {k}>
                  <img src = {pic.img} />
              </div>
           )
       })
      this.setState({
         slides //this is interpreted as {slides: slides}
      })

  }).catch(function(response){
       console.error(response)
  });
```